# SQL Custom datetime format to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, converters

I have a `varchar` which is coming through as the following format: `yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss`

I need to be able to convert that to a valid `datetime`, what will be the best method?

**Edit for example:**

```
DECLARE @d varchar = '2014-17-01 12:00:00'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @d, 103);
```

returns

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: Sorry, MSSQL (Sql Server 2012)

Comment: Is it possible to have it sent through as a some kind of Date data type i.e. `DATETIME`, `DATETIME2`, etc. instead?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name frantic Google searches don't say it does

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - `dd-MM`, not `MM-dd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via `CONVERT`?

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-31-01 17:00:00', 103 /* British */);

(No column name)
2014-01-31 17:00:00.000
```

Comment: `DECLARE @d varchar = '2014-17-01 12:00:00'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @d, 103);` Gets a conversion error

Comment: Because `DECLARE @d varchar = '2014-17-01 12:00:00'` is "`2`" (no size) you need `declare @d varchar(19)`

Comment: Rookie mistake - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to add SET DATEFORMAT.  This resolved the error for me and ensures everything gets into the correct bucket.

```
SET DATEFORMAT ydm

DECLARE @d VARCHAR(20) = '2014-17-01 12:00:00';
DECLARE @targetDate DATETIME = GETDATE(); -- Control Date
DECLARE @passedDate DATETIME = CAST(@d AS DATETIME);

SELECT @targetDate, @passedDate;
```

Comment: It may "work" but depending on what DATEFORMAT settings are in force, that may produce a datetime that is either the 4th of July or the 7th of April. Try running your query twice - once after `set dateformat mdy` and again after `set dateformat dmy` and compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONVERT as:

DECLARE @TodayDate datetime
SET @TodayDate  = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @TodayDate, 110) AS TodayDate

Output:

07-04-2014

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try to interchange day and month and then `PARSE` new string to datetime.

```
DECLARE @d varchar(50) = '2014-17-01 12:00:00'

DECLARE @year varchar(10) = SUBSTRING(@d,1,4)
DECLARE @day varchar(10) = SUBSTRING(@d,6,2)
DECLARE @month varchar(10) = SUBSTRING(@d,9,2)
DECLARE @time varchar(10) = SUBSTRING(@d,12,8)

DECLARE @new_d varchar(50) = @year+'-'+@month+'-'+@day+' '+@time

SELECT PARSE(@new_d AS datetime USING 'en-US') as Result
```